# async ForEach for a big collection

Tags: c#, asynchronous, collections, windows-phone

This collection contains about 500 or 1000 elements. In some cases there are several collections. In UI thread it works very slowly. I'm making silverlight app where async is only way to make app fast. I took very easy approach(withuot using any async operation or Task.Run() Method). This is example of first approach:

```
foreach (SpecialSongs.SongJSON futuresongs in pop)
{
    SpecialSongs.SongJSON sooong = new SpecialSongs.SongJSON();
    sooong.Artist = futuresongs.Artist;
    sooong.Duration = futuresongs.Duration;
    sooong.URI = futuresongs.URI;
    sooong.Title = futuresongs.Title;
    sooong.OwnerId = futuresongs.OwnerId;
    sooong.Id = futuresongs.Id;
    SpecialSongs.SongJSON songstocoll = new SpecialSongs.SongJSON();
    songstocoll.Artist = futuresongs.Artist;
    songstocoll.Duration = futuresongs.Duration;
    songstocoll.GenreId = futuresongs.GenreId;
    songstocoll.Id = futuresongs.Id;
    songstocoll.LyricsId = futuresongs.LyricsId;
    songstocoll.OwnerId = futuresongs.OwnerId;
    songstocoll.Title = futuresongs.Title;
    songstocoll.URI = futuresongs.URI;
    songstocoll.Song = sooong;
    popBindList.Add(songstocoll);
}
PopLongList.ItemsSource = popBindList;
PopText.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

The second approach: (little async)

```
RockLongList.ItemsSource = await Task<List<SpecialSongs.SongJSON>>.Run(() =>
{
    List<SpecialSongs.SongJSON> callback = new List<SpecialSongs.SongJSON>();
    foreach (SpecialSongs.SongJSON futuresongs in rock)
    {
        SpecialSongs.SongJSON sooong = new SpecialSongs.SongJSON();
        sooong.Artist = futuresongs.Artist;
        sooong.Duration = futuresongs.Duration;
        sooong.URI = futuresongs.URI;
        sooong.Title = futuresongs.Title;
        sooong.OwnerId = futuresongs.OwnerId;
        sooong.Id = futuresongs.Id;
        SpecialSongs.SongJSON songstocoll = new SpecialSongs.SongJSON();
        songstocoll.Artist = futuresongs.Artist;
        songstocoll.Duration = futuresongs.Duration;
        songstocoll.GenreId = futuresongs.GenreId;
        songstocoll.Id = futuresongs.Id;
        songstocoll.LyricsId = futuresongs.LyricsId;
        songstocoll.OwnerId = futuresongs.OwnerId;
        songstocoll.Title = futuresongs.Title;
        songstocoll.URI = futuresongs.URI;
        songstocoll.Song = sooong;
        callback.Add(songstocoll);
    }
    return callback;
});
RockText.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

I'm new to making loops using async. I found this example:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/04/10277325.aspx
,but i don't know how to use. Thanks, sorry for my english and formalization. I hope you decisions will solve my problem.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @YoryeNathan I need to make async foreach, because iteration that depends on my approach works very slowly and blocks UI Thread.

Comment: look into BackgroundWorker, its my favorite

Comment: An "async foreach" won't help you any more than `await Task.Run`, which you already have. Are you sure this is where the slowdown is coming from?

Comment: @StephenCleary  BackgroundWorker is solve all my problems. Thanks.